# Resource (resx) file import

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resx

I have problem after importing resource files from one project to another.

I work with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, C#, Visual Online.

I have Resource files in my projects. When I create a new project and import files and these resources to a new project, MY_RESOURCE.Designer.cs is not in its own MY_RESOURCE.resx section - it is next to it.

- Normally, order of Resource files must be like this:

  [image: Right order]

---

- But, in new project, it is like this - after importing:

  [image: Wrong order]

Also, in project's file (.csproj) I found, that structure of these files are different.

- Normally:

  ```
  <Compile Include="Resources\Main\Main.en-US.Designer.cs">
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <DependentUpon>Main.en-US.resx</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  ...
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Main\Main.en-US.resx">
    <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Main.en-US.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
  ```

---

- After import:

  ```
  <Compile Include="Resources\Main\Main.en-US.Designer.cs" />
  ...
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Main\Main.en-US.resx" />
  ```

I found some solutions like this problem's, to change Recourse's "Access Modifier" property (in it) from "No code generation" to "Public", but after this, resx file creates new child - MY_RESOURCE1.Designer.cs (not my MY_RESOURCE.Designer.cs), so this is not solution for my problem.

So, insted of importing them, I have to create new Resource file and copy and paste the words from the old project's resource files to new one.

Can someone advice me the way to bind a Designer.cs file to resx file insted of copy-paste..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# code ("Main.en-US.Designer.cs") is automatically generated by VS, you have to check that Visual Studio is correctly managing your resx file. To achieve this, check the Custom Tool property for your resx file:

1. Select your resx file
2. Open the Properties tab
3. Check "Custom Tool" property, make sure that "ResXFileCodeGenerator" value is present.

This should fix your issue.

Comment: But this is the same thing, to open resx file and change "Access Modifier" property from "No code generation" to "Internal". This way creates new Designer.cs in resx named MY_RESOURCE1.Designer.cs (not MY_RESOURCE.Designer.cs), and the old MY_RESOURCE.Designer.cs is next to MY_RESOURCE.resx again..

Comment: Yes, because you already have the MY_RESOURCE.Designer.resx in your project. I can't understand what you're trying to do, the C# file linked to resx usually is the autogenereted code to access resource from your code!

Comment: Yes, it is right way to add a new Designer.cs. Now I removed the old Designer.cs and changed "Access Modifier" property from "No code generation" to "Public". New one added in resx (and name is right: MY_RESOURCE.Designer.cs). I think it works.. But, is it right way? Is everything in its order in project? So, this is my solution and thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes in this way everything should be allright, as when you create a new resource file in project.

Answer (score 1):

I have had same issue before. I did finally the same, copy-pasting.
But have you tried changing the project file. Your new project should have this node inside designer file node:

```
<DependentUpon>Main.en-US.resx</DependentUpon>
```

I would say, first import the file, then edit your project file and add this node above, in your designer file node i.e.,

```
<Compile Include="Resources\Main\Main.en-US.Designer.cs">
```

Comment: I have this tag (<DependentUpon>Main.en-US.resx</DependentUpon>) in MY_PROJECT.csproj file, in old project.. I've changed tags of "MY_RESOURCE.resx" and "MY_RESOURCE.Designer.cs" and after open Visual Studio and project, everything was in its order (Designer.cs was in resx). But, as your advice - I have to add this tag from notepad or some other editor, yes? I thought there would be other way to solve it from Visual Studio... And, do you now, how to open project's Designer code from Visual Studio as text editor (as I opened and chaged it from notepad)? Thanks.